# Laravel can't copying 2 files to create

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create file unseen.arff from head.arff and data.csv
but I can't use copy command in laravel.
please help me

```php
$path = public_path('doc/');
$fp = fopen($path.'data.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
         
$process = new Process(['copy '.$path.'head.arff +'.$path.'data.csv '.$path.'unseen.arff']);
$process->run();
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: Why do you start a sub process just to copy a file? PHP can easily do this itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `file_put_contents`

```php
$path = public_path('doc/');
$fp = fopen($path.'data.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

$head = file_get_contents($path.'head.arff');
$data = file_get_contents($path.'data.csv');
file_put_contents($path.'unseen.arff', $head . $data);
```

If you realy want to use a shell command, which I don't recommend you can try using `cat` on both files and save the output in a new file:

```php
$process = new Process(['cat '.$path.'head.arff '.$path.'data.csv > '.$path.'unseen.arff']);
```